# Bonjour in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bonjour

I'm aware of [dnssd](https://github.com/tenderlove/dnssd), being a Ruby library for Apple's Bonjour protocol for network discovery for Mac OS X only, but is there a (relatively recent/complete) library that is cross platform?

Comment: Addendum: Places around the web seem to imply it works cross platform, but I have no way of testing. Anyone know?

Comment: I updated the link to dnssd because it was dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README](http://dnssd.rubyforge.org/dnssd/README_txt.html) on the project indicates that it is supported on non-OS X platforms:

> REQUIREMENTS:
>
> - OS X
> - The dns-sd library on other operating systems
> - avahi 0.6.25+

Looks like if you get the right support pieces you'll be fine.